# Order By before Group By in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have a problem when use `Order By` and `Group By` in a query string.

I want `Order By` before `Group By` but it's don't work.

I searched and find some solution but it don't work with me:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT minder_id, service_type_id
    FROM minder_service
    WHERE minder_id = 238
    AND deleted_at is null
    ORDER BY service_type_id ASC
) AS t
GROUP BY t.minder_id
```

- Run 1

  SELECT minder_id, service_type_id
  FROM minder_service
  WHERE minder_id = 238
  AND deleted_at is null
  ORDER BY service_type_id ASC

Result:
[Photo for Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZlRe.png)

- Run 2: Full
  [Photo for Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wZc7.png)

Please have a look at.

Thanks so much.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what you want to do by this query ? in this query not have any table name

Comment: do you want to lowest service_type_id ? If it is yes then use the DESC instead of ASC

Comment: Yes, i think use ASC to get  lowest service_type_id, but i  changed query to use DESC, result still = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the lowest service_type_id, you can use the MIN function:

```
SELECT minder_id, MIN(service_type_id)
FROM  minder_service
WHERE minder_id = 238 AND deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY minder_id
```

Also make sure deleted_at is really NULL for the record with service_type_id 1 if you say you expect that record.

Comment: You're welcome, but at stackoverflow the purpose is to mark the answer as accepted. This way, you're showing that it worked for you, and you're giving credit to the person who answered.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery returns an unordered set.  The database doesn't have to keep the order when passing the result of a subquery to an outer query, or when performing the `group by` operation.

You should rethink what you're trying to do.